# Radius of convergence of series if this particular condition is satisfied by coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I was solving questions from my analysis assignment and couldn't solve this.

> Let ${a_n}$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n -a_{n-1}|<\infty$. Then the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n , x\in \mathbb{R}$ is convergent

A) nowhere in $\mathbb{R}$

B) everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$

C) on some set containing (-1,1)

D) only on (-1,1)

The sequence $a_{n} =(1/2)^n$ satisfies condition and is convergent. So, A) is wrong. But how to contradict/verify other options?

Is there any theorem which can be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Behavior of $\sum a_n x^n$ given $\sum |a_n - a_{n-1}| < \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426989/behavior-of-sum-a-n-xn-given-sum-a-n-a-n-1-infty)

Comment: Consider the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$. It should be helpful for B) and D).